# Cannot create a numpy array using numpy's `full()` method and a python list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I can create a numpy array from a python list as follows:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = np.array(a).reshape(3,1)
>>> print(b)
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]]
```

However, I don't know what causes error in the following code:

Code :

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = np.full((3,1), a)
```

Error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-275-1ab6c109dda4> in <module>()
      1 a = [1,2,3]
----> 2 b = np.full((3,1), a)
      3 print(b)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in full(shape, fill_value, dtype, order)
    324         dtype = array(fill_value).dtype
    325     a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
--> 326     multiarray.copyto(a, fill_value, casting='unsafe')
    327     return a
    328 

<__array_function__ internals> in copyto(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (3,1)
```

Even though the list `a` has 3 elements inside it and I expect a 3x1 numpy array, the `full()` method fails to deliver it.
I referred the broadcasting article of numpy too. However, they are much more focused towards the arithmetic operation perspective, hence I couldn't obtain anything useful from there.

So it would be great if you can help me to understand the difference in b/w. the above mentioned array creation methods and the cause of the error too.

Comment: The assignment broadcasting rules are basically the same, expect it's only the `value` that can be changed - by adding a leading dimension and scaling the 1s.  If `a` was (3,) or (1,3) your `[1,2,3]` (which as array is (3,)) would fit.  Note that this use of `full` is just a `copyto` to a freshly created array.  You could make the same `a`, and do `a[:]=[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy is unable to broadcast the two shapes together because your list is interpreted as a 'row vector' (`np.array(a).shape = (3,)`) while you are asking for a 'column vector' (shape = `(3, 1)`).  If you are set on using `np.full`, then you can shape your list as a column vector initially:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> a = [[1],[2],[3]]
>>> b = np.full((3,1), a)
```

Another option is to convert `a` into a numpy array ahead of time and add a new axis to match the desired output shape.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a = np.array(a)[:, np.newaxis]
>>> b = np.full((3,1), a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you recommend a good source for exploring the restrictions with regards to array broadcasting (apart from numpy's article)?

Comment: Array broadcasting is a feature unique to numpy (and possibly other languages I don't use), but I don't think there is a general article which applies to multiple languages.  In other languages, you simply need to make sure that the shapes match while numpy is a little more flexible with it's broadcasting rules.  Have you seen [this article](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html)? Ot perhaps [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_broadcasting.htm) or [this one](https://machinelearningmastery.com/broadcasting-with-numpy-arrays/) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I'll go through them.